# Excel - Line Graph a specific day of the week

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a daily sales spreadsheet for the entire year - Weekday, Date, Orders, Guest, Sales in Columns (365 rows - one for each day). (There is more data to this table, and it is formatted and imported into Excel in rows for each day.)

[image: Current Spreadsheet Data]

I want to make 7 graphs, one for each day of the week (Mondays for example) to see how Total Sales for each day trends over time. How do I provide that logic in the graph parameter other than manually selecting each date, one by one?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Name the day column as "Day" and date column as "Date"
2. Create a Pivot table from your data
3. Use *Day* as Filters, *Date* as rows, and *Total sales* as Values
4. Than click on Analysis card -> Pivot table -> Options -> Show Report Filter Pages to create a set of new Sheets (days in week) with separate Pivot Tables.

[image: Example]

5. Then you can create charts from pivot table Options for each day in week (for each sheet)

Or you can choose a day in a Filter after step 3 and generate a chart from default Pivot table view.

Best regards, Lukas